# Dynamically change the default Text in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a set of items to a table in runtime with C#.

One of those items would be a **`TextBox`** and I would like to make it show something like "Input Number1", "Input Number2", and so on.

```
private void Add_Input_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabelaInputs.Controls.Add( new TextBox() {Text = "Input number {0}",InputCount });
```

Doesn't seems to be the right way...

Comment: that makes a new control, seems like you should just assign the text to the existing control

Comment: Yes it does @pm100, the idea is that i have a table and create a new control (in this case a textbox) with a default text that will change for every new control that i create

Comment: if franz answer is not correct then you need to explain what is going wrong

Comment: @pm100, it's absolutely perfect, but SO still want's me to think before accepting it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are missing is a call to `string.Format();`:

**C# 5:**

```
private void Add_Input_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabelaInputs.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = string.Format("Input number {0}", InputCount) });
}
```

**C# 6:**

```
private void Add_Input_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabelaInputs.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = $"Input number {InputCount}" });
}
```

Comment: first time i see c#6 new syntax in the wild

Comment: I just love it, it makes some code snippets so much more readable.

Comment: Thanks @franz-wimmer that was it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;
        private void Add_Input_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            new TextBox() { Name = "TextBox" + counter.ToString(), Text = "Input number " + counter.ToString() };
            counter++;
        }
```

This will create a new text box every time you click the button.